# printing multiple PDF files using print.js

Tags: javascript

I am building a list of PDFs from server side in HTML. In the list I'd like to include a  a print button . Is there some way to directly open the Print dialog for the PDF without the user seeing the PDF or opening a PDF viewer? Or Can I use print.Js Library in this case

Comment: The answer is probably "yes".  Q: Are you actually generating the .pdfs on the server side, and sending the binary data to the browser?

Comment: Thnak you paulsm4 , I'm trying to five the iframe tag in html the url of the pdf. I dont know if this is correct or not